# how to trigger notification from iPhone on iWatch

Tags: ios, notifications, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, watchkit

A noob question. I want to receive a notification when variable changes on the iOS app. to be clear. I want show notification on iWatch app when for example the user presses a button on the iOS App.

I have seen many tutorials for using the notifications interface. but all of them doesn't specify how to trigger the notifications from iPhone.

Anyone who knows a proper guide?

Thank you

Comment: You can do this easy way in iOS 9 beta SDK. Use WatchConnectivity Framework.

Comment: @NikitaZernov Does this mean that what i am asking can not be achieved without iOS 9 ?

Comment: No, it can be achieved

Comment: @NikitaZernov do you have a guide/tutorial for that ?

Answer (score 0):

Your notifications will go to your iPhone or your Apple Watch, depending on the device that you're using. 
iOS will take care of notifications if your ios app supports notifications.
[If your iPhone is unlocked, you get notifications on your iPhone, instead of your Apple Watch.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkA3t.jpg)

[If your iPhone is locked or asleep, and your Apple Watch is unlocked and on your wrist, you get notifications on your Apple Watch.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLDiB.jpg)